# check if at least one value exists in pandas dataframe index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

How can I check if at least one of the index of df2 is in df1?

```
df1
                             Val
StartDate                                                                   
2015-03-31                   NaN
2015-04-03                   NaN
2015-04-05                  8.08
2015-04-06                 23.48


df2
                               Val
StartDate                          
2015-03-31                     True
2015-04-01                     True
2015-04-02                     True
2015-04-03                     True
2015-04-04                     True
2015-04-05                     True
2015-04-06                     True


df2.index in df1.index
```

returns False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with [`Index.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.any.html) for check at least one `True`:

```
a = df1.index.isin(df2.index).any()
print (a)
True
```

Detail:

```
print (df1.index.isin(df2.index))
[ True  True  True  True]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[i for i in df1.index if i in df2.index]
```